# Entity relationship not reading correctly from database

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, relationship

I have an entity relationship setup in my mvc2 application such that each user has one role and each role can have many users. Like so:

```
 Roles         Users
--------     ---------
 RoleID--      UserID
         \
 Name     -->  RoleID
```

So a pretty basic many to one relationship enforced in the database and reflected in my entity relationship diagram. However when I try to get the user's role (`user.Role.Name`) it is always null, and I see in the database that the user's role is set to a valid ID. This is my first attempt at using entities as I had always used LINQ2SQL before and this is just baffling me.

What do?

Here's a screen shot of my edmx file

http://cl.ly/a9c088698369a54fc770

In the database the user table has a RoleID property (not sure why it isn't displaying in the diagram) and I am freely able to traverse from User to Role and it is known that it is a one to many relation to the compiler but it is just coming back as null when trying to view a user object.

EDIT:

Here's the query I use

```
User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
user.Role.Name
```

My user object isn't null and any of its other properties are visible just can't see the role, and each user has one role.

Comment: Show us the query you use to get your users.  You may have to do a Users.Roles.Load() to get them.

Comment: @Martin, answer the question and I will mark your answer, I didn't know you had to load references manually (I'm used to Linq2SQL)

Comment: Me too, started with Linq2SQL and now using EF4 on my latest project.  Lots of headaches, but some cool stuff too.

Comment: I got tired of it and switched to linq2sql for this project, it's pretty small scale so things like lazy loading aren't a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load any references manually like:

```
Users.Roles.Load()
```

**Added bonus:**

Get out the [generic repository](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/) ... awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Find the association between User and Role in the Model Browser, then make sure that the Role property is defined as a [Navigation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896321.aspx).

Comment: I don't see `RoleId` defined in your Users table.  Does it exist in the underlying database?  Is this POCO or defined using the modeler?

Comment: POCO? See my edit for more details, RoleID exists in the underlying DB, not sure why it wasn't added to the display.